# How to make a 0 stay as a 0 in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix

I use the following code to generate a matrix

```
randomdiv <-
  function(nchrom, ndivs, size) {
    sz <- matrix(nrow = nchrom, ncol = ndivs)
    for (j in 1:nchrom) {
      n <- size
      for (i in 1:ndivs)
      {
        old_subs <- rbinom (1, n, 0.5)
        num_chrom <- rep(1 / nchrom, nchrom)
        new_subs <- rmultinom(1, size * nchrom / 2, prob = c(num_chrom))
        m <- old_subs + new_subs
        sz[j,i] <- m[1,1]
        n <- m
      }
    }
    return (sz)
  }

>randomdiv(3, 3, 10)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]   11   13   12
  [2,]    6    8    5
  [3,]   12   11    9
```

The only adjustment I need to make is that when a 0 is generated in the column by the `rbinom` function, I need that occurence to stay as a 0 for the remainder of the matrix, but anything `>0` needs to go through the rest of the loop and have `new_subs` added to it.

I have tried;

```
randomdiv <- function(nchrom, ndivs, size) {sz <- matrix(nrow = nchrom, ncol = ndivs) 

for (j in 1:nchrom) {
     n <- size
for (i in 1:ndivs)
     {
      old_subs <- rbinom (1, n, 0.5)  
      num_chrom <- rep(1/nchrom, nchrom)    
      new_subs <- rmultinom(1, size*nchrom/2, prob = c(num_chrom))
      m <- ifelse(old_subs>0, old_subs + new_subs, old_subs+0)         
      sz[j,i] <- m[1,1]
      n <- m
     }
    }
   return (replicate(ncell, sz, simplify = FALSE))
  }
> randomdiv(3, 3, 10)
#Error in m[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I've tried a few different tactics with the `ifelse` function, but I think it only treats the columns as a whole, so if there is a 0 at all, nothing happens for the whole column, whereas I need each value in the columns to be treated individually.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what randomdiv should do? As it is now your question is reely hard to understand

Comment: @nist I understand it's not easy to understand, I find it really hard to simplify it as just putting numbers in doesn't do the same function... `randomdiv()` generates a matrix based on the parameters you can see in the top line of code. So the `size` parameter goes through the `rbinomial` to roughly halve them for each row (defined by `nchrom`, in the example i've given this is 3). I then use `rmultinomial` to generate values which should be added to the values generated by `rbinom` and this combined number is the actual outputted value in the matrix - it just loops

Comment: Perhaps add a sample desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `if()` with an `else` and skip several lines of code if there's a 0:

```
randomdiv <-
  function(nchrom, ndivs, size) {
    sz <- matrix(nrow = nchrom, ncol = ndivs)
    for (j in 1:nchrom) {
      n <- size
      for (i in 1:ndivs)
      {
        old_subs <- rbinom (1, n, 0.5)
        if(old_subs>0){
          num_chrom <- rep(1 / nchrom, nchrom)
          new_subs <- rmultinom(1, size * nchrom / 2, prob = c(num_chrom))
          m <- old_subs + new_subs
          sz[j,i] <- m[1,1]
        } else sz[j,i] <- old_subs
        n <- m
      }
    }
    return (sz)
  }

randomdiv(3, 3, 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    0
# [2,]    1    2    4
# [3,]    1    1    0
```